# What password is used for developer mode in Squarespace if the login provider is Google?

Tags: git, google-oauth, squarespace

I enabled Developer Mode on a Squarespace site that I created with a Google account. When I attempt to clone the site, I am prompted for a login, but I do not know what password to use. When enabling Developer Mode in Squarespace, there is a "CONNECTIVITY DETAILS" section where the password is just asterisks. I tried the Google password and an app password, but neither worked. Squarespace says that "They are the same credentials you use to log into your Squarespace site".
https://developers.squarespace.com/using-git#CloningaTemplate

Answer (score 0):

The app password started to work. The answer is here:
https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545717
"...you use social login. In either case, you'll need to create an app password to log in"